# Set IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() to true in VS Code on OSX

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a MVC 6 project with VS Code and OSX. How can I specify my current environment as "Development" so that IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() will return true?

I have tried to set the "ASPNET_ENV" config setting to "Development" in the JSON file I specified through ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(), but this does not work.

```
{
    "AppSettings": 
    {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
    }   
}
```

Appreciate the help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the development environment through an environment variable:

```
EXPORT ASPNET_ENV=Development
```

Comment: Or to quickly switch to different environments from the command line use `dnx web ASPNET_Env=Development` or `dnx-watch web ASPNET_Env=Development`. This overrides your environment variable value.